# Change GUID in lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, sandbox-solution, feature-activation

I have a **sandbox** solution in SharePoint . I have created number of site columns, Content Types , list definitions and list instances. Everything has individual feature.

For Ex:

1. Site column feature (Site feature)
2. Site content type feature (Site feature)
3. List destination feature (Web feature)
4. List instance (Web feature)

I have 3 **lookup columns** which is provisioned successfully without target list.

Lookup column is configured in Content Type and list instance.

Now, I want to update that lookup field using feature receiver and use lookup value in other list.

What should I Do? My lookup Column *element.xml* is below.

```
<Field
ID="{a41ab4e5-a30a-4d99-8e0b-1ab2095d68f2}"
Name="Client"
DisplayName="Client"
Type="Lookup"
Required="TRUE"
Group="Test"
List="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
ShowField="Title">
```

How can I replace list ID with `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`?

Comment: Once the list and fields are created, load the lookup field (SPFieldLookup) and update the relevant members of the field. Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @Prakash-CrowCanyon It is  not working , Because i have restriction of sand box solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
lstevents = web.Lists["Test"];
fldLookupField = (SPFieldLookup)web.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Test");
fldLookupField.SchemaXml = fldLookupField.SchemaXml.Replace("List=\"{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\"", string.Format("List=\"{0}\"", lstevents.ID.ToString("B")));
fldLookupField.LookupWebId = lstevents.ParentWeb.ID;
fldLookupField.Update(true);
```

Comment: Please add some description about the code. It will be useful for other readers.

Comment: @Sharepoint. Add some Description and not copy paste the same answer which is given by others.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, i got the solution of my question . I am sharing with you guys.

```
lstevents = web.Lists["Test"];
                    fldLookupField = (SPFieldLookup)web.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Test");
                    fldLookupField.SchemaXml = fldLookupField.SchemaXml.Replace("List=\"{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\"", string.Format("List=\"{0}\"", lstevents.ID.ToString("B")));
                    fldLookupField.LookupWebId = lstevents.ParentWeb.ID;
                    fldLookupField.Update(true);
```

Add this code to feature activated of List Instances. You can change source id of look up column using this code.